# enable internet on openvpn tun - azure linux

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, iptables, openvpn

I am trying to do this with `OpenVPN` `TUN` on an `Azure` `Linux` instance:

`-=Android Client=- --> -=VPS=- --> -=Internet=-`

Client connects but no internet access.

**Iptables commands**

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 191.236.xxx.xxx`

(public virtual internet ip from azure)

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 100.75.xxx.xxx`

(the ip of `eth0` from `ifconfig` - internal azure ip)

**Iptables output**

```
# iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
SNAT       all  --  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere             to:191.236.xxx.xxx
SNAT       all  --  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere             to:191.236.xxx.xxx
SNAT       all  --  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere             to:191.236.xxx.xxx
SNAT       all  --  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere             to:191.236.xxx.xxx
SNAT       all  --  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere             to:100.75.xxx.xxx
```

**Forwarding**

```
# cat /etc/sysctl.conf | grep forw
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

**server.conf**

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

**Syslog**

```
Nov  2 17:19:58 azu-1 ovpn-server[1711]: 109.242.144.133:11810 [azu1-mx4] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]109.242.144.133:11810
Nov  2 17:19:58 azu-1 ovpn-server[1711]: azu1-mx4/109.242.144.133:11810 MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=10.8.0.6, IPv6=(Not enabled)
Nov  2 17:19:58 azu-1 ovpn-server[1711]: azu1-mx4/109.242.144.133:11810 MULTI: Learn: 10.8.0.6 -> azu1-mx4/109.242.144.133:11810
Nov  2 17:19:58 azu-1 ovpn-server[1711]: azu1-mx4/109.242.144.133:11810 MULTI: primary virtual IP for azu1-mx4/109.242.144.133:11810: 10.8.0.6
Nov  2 17:19:59 azu-1 ovpn-server[1711]: azu1-mx4/109.242.144.133:11810 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
Nov  2 17:19:59 azu-1 ovpn-server[1711]: azu1-mx4/109.242.144.133:11810 send_push_reply(): safe_cap=940
Nov  2 17:19:59 azu-1 ovpn-server[1711]: azu1-mx4/109.242.144.133:11810 SENT CONTROL [azu1-mx4]: 'PUSH_REPLY,route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222,dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220,route 10.8.0.1,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.6 10.8.0.5' (status=1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Well, that was luck - found a solution fast :)

Posting in case anyone benefits - this is what worked for me:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun+ -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Thx, Works for me as well after hours of testing iptables rules.